# jQuery for manipulating IU on the client

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I am starting to learn jQuery programming and would like to ask for assistance in writing this snippet of code.

There is a **ul** list of several **li** items. Each **li** has the following structure

```
 <li><a href="http://www.findadeal.com/city-state/"/>City</li>
```

where city-state and City are hard coded values of any city, say

```
 <li><a href="http://www.findadeal.com/buffalo-ny/"/>Buffalo</li>
```

When the page is requested a product classification parameter, say "beer", is sent in a query string.

I need to modify the **li** links to the obtain following form during the page load.

```
 <li><a href="http://www.findadeal.com/buffalo-ny/beer/"/>Buffalo Beer</li>
```

How would I code the looping logic with jQuery so that each **li** elemnt is modified accordingly. There are usually no more than 50 cities on a page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but I think this might get you on your way.

```
$('li').each(function(){ //grab all li elements and loop through them
   var $this = $(this); //capture the jquery object for use later
   $this.find('a').attr('href','your new text');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Assigning an href value to <a> element is working fine but for some reason the final href is NOT what I expected. I will create a new post for that.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can pass the `text()` function another function and the return value of that function will be the new value for the current element.

```
//wait for document.ready to fire before doing anything
$(function () {

    //check to see if there is a query-string or not
    if (window.location.search != '') {

        //split the query-string by ampersands
        var parameters = window.location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');

        //iterate through the query-string key/value pairs
        for (var i = 0, len = parameters.length; i < len; i++) {

            //get the key/value pair split into an array
            var pair = parameters[i].split('=');

            //if the key is the correct one then we can proceed
            if (pair[0] == 'product-classification') {

                //update each `li` element with the value of the `product-classification` query-string variable
                $('li').text(function () {

                    //add the value to the current text of the `li` element
                    return $(this).text() + ' ' + pair[1];
                });

                //now we can stop the loop because we have done what we want, if there are lots of query-string parameters this will be a good idea
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LQXWz/

Docs for `.text()`: http://api.jquery.com/text